# PHP Unicode codepoint to character

Tags: php, unicode

I would like to convert Unicode codepoint to character. Here is what I have tried:

```
$point = dechex(127468);  // 1f1ec

echo "\u{1f1ec}";         // this works
echo "\u{$point}";        // this outputs '\u1f1ec'
echo "\u{{$point}}";      // Parse error: Invalid UTF-8 codepoint escape sequence
echo "\u\{{$point}\}";    // outputs \u\{1f1ec\}
echo "\u{". $point ."}";  // Parse error; same as above
```

Comment: Ah well. Seems like a lost situation if its just not possible that way :) The answer below makes sense though.

Comment: Also try simply `echo "\u1f1ec";`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to convert integer to hexadecimal string, instead use [IntlChar::chr](http://php.net/manual/en/intlchar.chr.php):

```
echo IntlChar::chr(127468);
```

Directly from docs of `IntlChar::chr`:

> Return Unicode character by code point value

Comment: Cool beans. I'll have to bookmark this, as I'm sure I'm going to run into this later and go "what was that again???" :)

Answer (score 1):

For PHP>=7.2

```php
$point = 127468;

var_dump( mb_chr($point) );
```

Output:

```
string(4) ""
```

Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-chr.php

Answer (score 0):

For those not having `IntlChar` or `Intl` available one can avoid the evil `eval()` function by going the [SGML route, where entity parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference) is available since PHP 4 already. For this one has to know the notation for entities in [HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/charset.html#h-5.3.1) or [XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-references) and then use either the earlier available function [`mb_decode_numericentity()`](https://www.php.net/mb_decode_numericentity) or the more known function [`html_entity_decode()`](https://www.php.net/html_entity_decode). Both support any entity notation - either decimal or hexadecimal:

```php
<?php

    $iPoint= 127468;  // Decimal
    $sPoint= dechex( $iPoint );  // Hexadecimal = '1f1ec'

    // Available since PHP 4.0.6
    $aMap= array( 0, 0x10ffff );
    $sOut1= mb_decode_numericentity( '&#x'. $sPoint. ';', $aMap, 'UTF-8' );  // &#x1f1ec;
    $sOut2= mb_decode_numericentity( '&#'.  $iPoint. ';', $aMap, 'UTF-8' );  // &#127468;

    // Available since PHP 4.3.0
    $sOut3= html_entity_decode     ( '&#x'. $sPoint. ';', 0,     'UTF-8' );  // &#x1f1ec;
    $sOut4= html_entity_decode     ( '&#'.  $iPoint. ';', 0,     'UTF-8' );  // &#127468;

    echo "$sOut1 $sOut2 $sOut3 $sOut4";
```

This is a bit of an overkill, tho. String concatenation won't work since at any time you already produce a literal, and literals cannot be changed.

---

A different approach is to use the fact that [UTF-32 always consists of 4 bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32) for each character, so one can use the hexadecimal code point and turn its textual representation into its binary form (using [`pack()`](https://www.php.net/pack)) to then convert from that into UTF-8 (using [`mb_convert_encoding()`](https://www.php.net/mb_convert_encoding)):

```php
<?php

    $iPoint= 127468;  // Decimal
    $sPoint= dechex( $iPoint );  // Hexadecimal = '1f1ec'

    // UTF-32 always uses 4 bytes per character, so the hex value ('1f1ec') must have leading zeroes ('0001f1ec').
    while( strlen( $sPoint )< 8 ) {
        $sPoint= '0'. $sPoint;
    }

    // Convert hex string of 8 bytes into its binary counterpart of 4 bytes.
    $sBinary= pack( 'H*', $sPoint );

    // Just convert 1 character of 4 bytes (UTF-32) into UTF-8 (which are 4 different bytes for this character).
    echo mb_convert_encoding( $sBinary, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-32' );  // From: 0x00 01 f1 ec   To: 0xf0 9f 87 ac
```

> | Unicode code point | character | UTF-8 | name |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | U+1F1EC |  | f0 9f 87 ac | [REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER G](https://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=127462) |

Answer (score -2):

Actually find the solution after several hours:

```
$unicode = '1F605'; //
$uni = '{' . $unicode; // First bracket needs to be separated, otherwise you get '\u1F605'

$str = "\u$uni}";

eval("\$str = \"$str\";"); // Turns unicode into RegEx and store it as $str
echo $str;
```

Thanks @Rick James for the idea with the eval() function

Answer (score -2):

PHP 7+ solution snippet:

```php
function charFromCodePoint($codepoint) {
    eval('$ch = "\u{'.dechex($codepoint).'}";');
    return $ch;
}
```

Notice, that PHP5 doesn't support the "\u{}" syntax.