# Unicode codepoint escape syntax

Tags: php, unicode, character-encoding, symbols

I'm trying to use "Unicode codepoint escape syntax" to display emoji by its unicode.

The basic syntax is:

```
echo "\u{1f606}"; - And it works fine
```

However when i insert the unicode from variable:

```
$unicode = "1f606";
echo "\u{".$unicode."}";
```

I get «Invalid UTF-8 codepoint escape sequence» error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Unicode codepoint to character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48432078/php-unicode-codepoint-to-character)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use "\u{}" notation for conversion, use mb_chr() instead.

Example:

```
$unicode= 0x1f606;
echo mb_chr($unicode);
```