# why Unicode codepoint escape syntax doesn't work in php

Tags: php, unicode, escaping, codepoint

i am confuse about Unicode codepoint escape syntax. here is a demo

```
//this work fine 
echo "\u{1f602}"; // echoes 
//this doesn't work
$var = '1f602';
echo '"\u{' . $var . '}"';// out put \u1f602
```

after i search. i find eval will let it work correct

```
$var = '1f602';
eval('$re = "\u{' . $var . '}";');
echo $re; //echoes
```

so i wanna to know the reason, what cause this?
how internal of php process it?
not support on the runtime?
thanks!!!

Comment: thanks, i think it is not single quoted or double quoted problem. i has try it both. Neither works. @Ivar

Comment: Right. It does matter (it will never work using single quotes), but that's only part of the problem.

Comment: The first one matches `\u{[0-9A-Fa-f]+}`, the second doesn't. Also single quotes won't be parsed. `"\u{" . $var . "}"` would be closer but still doesn't match.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: You can't do it with the double quote expansion. The question is about `why` not `how`, right? For how see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48432078/php-unicode-codepoint-to-character

Comment: thanks, i wanna to know why,  why eval will let it work? or say why "\u{" . $var . "}"  not complies with  [the \u{} syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.unicode-codepoint-escape-syntax) @user3783243

Comment: The PHP expands the `$var` first to run the `eval` so you end up with `$re = "\u{1f602}";` which will run natively in PHP because it matches the regex the double quote expander uses. I don't know how to do it without the `eval` well using the double quote expansion.

Comment: @user3783243 :  how u test it whether matches the regex the double quote expander uses? sorry,  what is double quote expander, something like php Interpreter?  i guess the \u{} syntax only work in compile, not in runtime, i doesn't have enough knowledge to know if my guess is correct

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double that is what converts it to the emoji, also what converts variables to value.